# Why I received an "No such property" on dbm-update with grails dbm-migration plugin?

Tags: grails, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate my actual database to another one on my Grails app.

So I'm using the [plugin migration](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/). I follow steps described in user guide but when I try the command : `dbm-update` (to update my new DB), I receive the error :

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: SOURCE for class: Script1
        at Script1$_run_closure1_closure54.doCall(Script1.groovy:1336)
        at Script1$_run_closure1_closure54.doCall(Script1.groovy)
        at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.super$3$invokeMethod(DslBuilder.groovy) ...
```

Do you have any idea or advice?

Comment: looks like your migration file is not correct - plz paste it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no occurence of `SOURCE` in the plugin, so it must be in one of your migration scripts.